# Missing operator in query expression?

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, syntax-error

This code is giving me a syntax error.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = ""
dAdapt = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select CustName, CustMobileNo, SMSDate, OilChangeStatus from invoiceHeader_tb where SMSDate =" & DTPDueDate.Value & " order by SMSDate", con)
Dim dt As New DataTable
dAdapt.Fill(dt)
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
Me.DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
Me.DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
con.Close()
```

Error:

> syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SMSDate
>   =25-Feb-16 4:05PM'

Comment: `New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select CustName, CustMobileNo, SMSDate, OilChangeStatus from invoiceHeader_tb where SMSDate ='" & DTPDueDate.Value & "' order by SMSDate", con)`  use this

Answer (score 1):

Add single quote here

```
SMSDate = '" & DTPDueDate.Value & "'
```

So it will be like this

```
dAdapt = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select CustName, CustMobileNo, SMSDate, OilChangeStatus from invoiceHeader_tb where SMSDate ='" & DTPDueDate.Value & "' order by SMSDate", con)
```

Comment: still facing data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: SMSDate is datetime or string?

Comment: smsDate is a short date(format = 2/23/2016), I am storing through DateTimePicker tools.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing apostrophes (single quotes) around your date.

```
where SMSDate ='" & DTPDueDate.Value & "' order
```

Comment: still facing data type mismatch in expression

Answer (score 0):

Your raw SQL is missing single quotes around the date value, **but that still may not fix the error** because the db may be expecting the date in a certain format.

You haven't specified the db you are using but most expect the date in 'yyy-MM-dd' format

Also this way of executing sql also leaves you open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) Vulnerabilities so you should do this properly with a **parameterised query**:

For exmaple:

```
Public Function GetBarFooByBaz(ByVal Baz As String) As String
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz= @Baz"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string here"), _
        cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Baz", Baz)
        Return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
    End Using
End Function
```

Reference from this answer:[How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)

Doing it this way means you don't have to set the date in a specific format and you also don't have to remember whether you need quotes around a value or not.

Comment: Parameters are important and is a must and great to do now if he isn't. However `you don't have to set the date in a specific format` I disagree with that statement. There are different types for dates, looking at the `SqlDBType` enumeration currently there are three and each one is different in context. Depending on his column type and what he passes in `will make a difference`. On another note wrapping the command in a using statement is best as well, it prevents a call to the finalizer which when the command is disposed is an enhancement.

Comment: @Codexer - I have changed the answer to give more detail and also to use `AddWithValue` which does not require you to specify the `SqlDbType`

Comment: Fair enough, but `AddWithValue` ***isn't any better***; it relies on the DB to implicitly cast that value passed in being it's an object at that point. I like to specify my types to what they are and not solely rely on the implicit casting of SQL to do this. Furthermore `AddWithValue` is a performance thing, it is a anti-pattern because of the performance issues related to the parameter type and it's size.